# How do i compare two ArryList and extract only two similar Indexes? (demontration in the last comment of the code) (SOLVED!)

Tags: arraylist, compare

import java.util.ArrayList;

// This code will generate 20 different dates and store each 10 of them within two different ArrayLists:

public class similarIndexes {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
```

//      The two main ArrayList which store the dates:

```
    ArrayList<String> birthdates1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> birthdates2 = new ArrayList<String>();
```

//      Defining the max amount of Years, Months and days for the random generator:

```
    int maxY = 2010;
    int minY = 2020;

    int maxM = 12;
    int minM = 1;

    int maxD = 30;
    int minD = 1;
```

//      A (for) loop to add the dates and store them in the first ArrayList, them iterate through the contents and print them out:

```
    System.out.println("First List: ");
    for(int i = 0; i < 51; i++) {
```

//      Creating the random dates, adding them to the ArrayList and itereating through them and printing them out:

```
        int Year = (int)(Math.random() * (maxY - minY + 1) + minY);
        int Month = (int)(Math.random() * (maxM - minM + 1) + minM);
        int Day = (int)(Math.random() * (maxD - minD + 1) + minD);
        
        birthdates1.add(Day+ "/" +Month+ "/" +Year);
        
        System.out.println("Index ["+i+"] Contains a date of: " +birthdates1.get(i));
        
    }
```

//      Same with the first (for) loop, this stores the dates in the second loop, then iterate through them and print them out:

```
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Second List: ");
    for(int i = 0; i < 51; i++) {
```

//      Creating the random dates, adding them to the ArrayList and itereating through them and printing them out:

```
        int Year = (int)(Math.random() * (maxY - minY + 1) + minY);
        int Month = (int)(Math.random() * (maxM - minM + 1) + minM);
        int Day = (int)(Math.random() * (maxD - minD + 1) + minD);
        
        birthdates2.add(Day+ "/" +Month+ "/" +Year);
        
        System.out.println("Index ["+i+"] Contains a date of: " +birthdates2.get(i));
```

//          Made an if condition when it detects two indexes with the same value it print out an arrow pointing to the index:

```
        if(birthdates1.get(i).equals(birthdates2.get(i))) {
            System.out.print("    <---------------------    ");
        }
    }
    
}
```

}

Comment: You did not demonstrate when you consider two dates as _similar_.

Comment: How do i define this to the java program?

Comment: First of all you have to define this to yourself.

Comment: That.. I don't exactly know what u meant by that comment but ironically, it helped me a lot, I solved my problem, Thanks for your help :)